# How Can I Return Specified Image Size From Google Cloud Storage With Node API?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using cloud storage and it is working well, I just don't want to return the full-size image every time. I'm wondering if there is a way to specify a width to resize an image to when I request it?

Here is the WORKING code. I just need to return smaller images, say, 300px wide (maintaining original aspect ratio). This number could change or fluctuate, so I don't want to save a ton of different versions at different sizes unless I absolutely have to.

```
var fileName = "Image.png";

var stream = bucket.file(fileName).createReadStream();

res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': imageInfo.mime_type });

stream.on('data', function (data) {
  res.write(data);
});

stream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('error reading stream', err);
});

stream.on('end', function () {
  res.end();
});
```

I've found this site explaining how to do this in PHP, so I'm guessing there is probably a way to do this in node?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article should get you off on the right foot: “Uploading, Resizing and Serving images with Google Cloud Platform” @Lipis https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556

Comment: That makes a ton of sense for public URLs, mine happen to be private, which is why I'm looking to do this directly through the node API.

Comment: Are they private as in they can't be viewed without authentication or they are publicly read only?

Comment: They can't be viewed without authentication. Every single image is protected (not just a secret link, but a user has to be logged in to see the image).

Comment: It seems like the image resizing and whether or not the user is authenticated are different concerns. You should be able to use the strategy above but have security rules tied to the downloading/viewing of all resources in your image store.